# SQLException:class org.apache.commons.dbutils.BeanProcessor (in module commons.dbutils) cannot access class Zhang because module BeanListHandlerDemo

Tags: java, mysql

I have searched solution for a long time on the net but have not found. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

**Select from table**

```
String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gjp?serverTimezone=UTC";
String user = "root";
String password = "snn0924";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);     
String sql="select * from gjp_zhangwu";     
QueryRunner qr=new QueryRunner();
Object[] params= {};
ZhangWu zw =
    qr.query(conn, sql, new BeanHandler<ZhangWu>(ZhangWu.class), params);
```

It seems that the question is in the last line,but how to use "BeanHandler"?

Comment: Which JDK version are you on?

Comment: thanks, it is java 11

Comment: And I suppose you have a module-info file, right?

Comment: yes.what`s wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Check the answer and let me know.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works by using "exports *.package".

Comment: awesome! Consider marking the answer as accepted so other people know that this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the *unnamed module* from Apache Commons DBUtils cannot access your classes.

That happens because you're using the *Java Platform Module System*.
To solve this problem you need to export your packages, so that the Apache module can see them.

```
module your.module {
   ...
   exports your.package;
}
```

`your.package` is the package under which your `Zhang` class resides, with every other class that needs to be used with it.

You classes must also be declared `public`.

---

Once you saw that this way it works, you might want to try de-escalating the visibility of your classes, using

```
opens your.package;
```

instead.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks so much for your answer, i`ll try it.